# Calculate a point's position relative to the parent's transform

Tags: c#, .net, math

I'm trying to make my own `Transform` system similar to Unity's but it's in a 2D space

I get everything (positions, rotations, scale) works except, for localPosition - Which tells the local position of an object relative to it's parent's transform.

In Unity, this can be done by calling `Transform.InverseTransformPoint` function but since it's code is hidden and that I'm making it in 2D space, I can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

you need to use matrix transformation for hierarchies transform.
here is some information about this:

> https://paroj.github.io/gltut/Positioning/Tut06%20Fun%20with%20Matrices.html
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgQzOmnBGCo
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrggOvOSZr4
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09I15RO49vg

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).